# Scaling Embedded youtube video in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am having trouble with this red border at the right hand side when embedding a youtube video in a UIWebView. No matter what I do to rescale the image it will never get rid of this and fill the cell properly

[image]

the embedding code is:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 320\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"320\" height=\"210\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"320\" height=\"210\"></embed></object></div></body></html>", self.videoID, self.videoID];
```

This is loaded using:

```
  [_youtubeWebView loadHTMLString:tvFeedItem.htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

This shows a section in 3d showing the red border is actually inside and part of the WEbViews content

[image]

Comment: Check your web view width.

Comment: The WebView width is 320, the full width of the device, the red border is actually being shown on the webView which is odd

Comment: actually i have net problem now will tell you later. don't worry i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

There is extra "" after your "object" tag.
check your HTML carefully
In your HTML tags are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something similar, maybe this can help?:

```
        youtubePlayer.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        youtubePlayer.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.0, -10.0, -10.0, -10.0)
        youtubePlayer.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(youtubePlayer.frame.width)\" height=\"\(youtubePlayer.frame.height + 20)\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

important NOTE: about the embedHTMLString.

(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1

^ the ?&playsinline=1 is very important